# How to connect a web site to a geth node?

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, web3js

Before the DApp-browser Mist was available, this [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) library seems the way to go on building a bridge from contract to a frontend (web site).

But, I cannot get the very [basic examples](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) to work.

These sources lack a few major points:

1. What is the exact command to start geth to run the examples? I have used:

   ```
   geth --rpc console 2
   ```

   while mining etc.
2. This [example](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/example/balance.html) has the line:

   ```
   web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider());
   ```

   Should it be localhost?

   ```
   web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
   ```
3. Is there anyway to hide `web3.setProvider` and other JavaScript code from the page source viewable for the user? If the geth node address is public, that could be a security problem.

Maybe I'm asking obvious questions here, but it shouldn't be too much trouble to add at least the geth starting argument to the tutorials. The best case scenario would be to have step by step guide with no assumptions left blank.

Comment: Same problem. I am trying to use web3.js (or web3.min.js) within my NW.js app. My index.html file contains: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/web3.js/master/dist/web3.min.js"> </script> I have tried this, and also tried doing 'npm init' and 'npm install ethereum/web3.js --save' - I get a similar error in both cases. TypeError: e is not a function at chrome-extension://kbkmobamaomphkjgbgdnoonjhcdgmell/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:1:59528 at chrome-extension://kbkmobamaomphkjgbgdnoonjhcdgmell/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:1:60409 at XMLHttp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For point number one, this should work:
`geth --rpc  --rpccorsdomain="*" console 2>> geth.log`
Running `--rpccorsdomain="*"` is dangerous though, especially if you have unlocked accounts. Put your domain name instead of `*`. For localhost, add `--rpcaddr="localhost"`

Comment: The danger of course is that websites can spend your ether and even send it to themselves. (Without any prompting or anything!) Every time I saw a site telling users to do this, it felt like the users were getting scammed. Stick to Mist / Ethereum Wallet, they are the official ones and will ask you before transferring funds.

Answer (score 5):

To add to [Ethan Wilding's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/648/45919), for safely testing locally you can use the `--dev` flag and connect to the node with username 'test' and password 'test'.

So the `geth` command for testing becomes:
 
`geth --dev --rpc  --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcaddr="localhost"`

**[caution: you should only use these flags for local dev mode testing, never on a real network]**

And connecting the web3.js client is:
`web3.setProvider(web3.providers.HttpProvider(null, 0, 'test', 'test'));`
where null sets the host to `http://localhost:8545` and 0 disables the timeout

Once that's done the sample code will connect to the the local node, although there's a good chance (at least for now) that a lot of samples won't work because they don't seem to be up-to-date. But **web3.js/example/balance.html** works nicely.

Comment: `--rpccorsdomain="*"` is the least safe one.

Comment: you're not wrong in general, but for dev testing on a local server? i'll add a note not to do this in production :)