# Save array to text file from geth command line

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, command-line

I have an array `myArray` on the geth command line of 1000 elements. When I type `myArray` on the geth console, it prints to screen. I'd like to pipe this to a text file. My development setup uses testrpc and go-ethereum with analysis of post-scripts in Python.

At the moment I'm cutting and pasting from geth. I sense there may be a much better way of doing it, but can't seem to find an example on searching.

**Is there a simple way to save an array to file from the go-ethereum javascript command line?**

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using the geth console as opposed to nodeJS and web3? The geth console is pretty limited compared Node.

Comment: @TjadenHess force of habit mainly... it has worked ok up to now.

Comment: The geth console is essentially just a stripped-down node console. All your scripts will still work in node, and you can actually use libraries and files.

Comment: @TjadenHess do you happen to know how I'd start node with the equivalent of:  `geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545`? Thanks

Comment: Found it here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/unable-to-connect-ethereum-node-even-rpc-port-8545-is-open

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The geth console doesn't seem like the best tool for the job. A better method would be to use NodeJS + web3.

Just follow [these instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#adding-web3) to connect web3 to your testrpc, then you can use exactly the same script as before, but write to a file using

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync("myfile.txt", myArray);
```

Comment: Crucial thing to add, to run same script, was `var eth = web3.eth;`

Comment: N.b. `nodejs+web3+testrpc` is noticably slower than `geth+testrpc`, for my script.