# Can't connect to localhost:8545 while using ethereumjs-testrpc web3?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapps, testrpc, connections

I am developing a simple Voting dApp by following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2). In this tutorial 
we are using `npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3` so that we can get the fake nodes of Ethereum.

For that i first created the object of web3 by using `Web3 = require('web3')` command in the Node.js command prob. After using the command i should get all the attributes of Web3. But i am only getting `[Function: Web3]`.

After that i am using web3 to connect to the localhot:8545 by using `web3 = new Web3("http://localhost:8545")` in the Node.js command prob. To check that i am connected to localhost:8485 i am using `web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log)`. I should get addresses as follows;

```
['0x9c02f5c68e02390a3ab81f63341edc1ba5dbb39e',
'0x7d920be073e92a590dc47e4ccea2f28db3f218cc',
'0xf8a9c7c65c4d1c0c21b06c06ee5da80bd8f074a9',
'0x9d8ee8c3d4f8b1e08803da274bdaff80c2204fc6',
'0x26bb5d139aa7bdb1380af0e1e8f98147ef4c406a',
'0x622e557aad13c36459fac83240f25ae91882127c',
'0xbf8b1630d5640e272f33653e83092ce33d302fd2',
'0xe37a3157cb3081ea7a96ba9f9e942c72cf7ad87b',
'0x175dae81345f36775db285d368f0b1d49f61b2f8',
'0xc26bda5f3370bdd46e7c84bdb909aead4d8f35f3']
```

All i need is one of those addresses to proceed further. But i am getting an error which says that  Connection refused or URL couldn't be resolved as follows;

```
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [],
     [Symbol(kWeak)]: WeakReference {} } }
> Error: Connection refused or URL couldn't be resolved: http://localhost:8545
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 7\FYP\New One\node_modules\web3-providers\dist\web3-providers.cjs.js:759:22)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 7\FYP\New One\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 7\FYP\New One\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 7\FYP\New One\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:349:14)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 7\FYP\New One\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:252:61)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20) null
```

I also check a relevant [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9943/54194) to my question in this stack exchange. But this answer is telling to use [truffle](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs) instead of solving the above problem. And if comments of this answer are solving the above problem then they are perhaps solving it for actual web3 not for ethereumjs-testrpc web3.

I am using solidity and if you need the code i can edit my question.

Comment: Are you referring to the latest version of the tutorial? The latest version edited in Fed 2019 seems to use ganache-cli which is what  testrpc is known as now. Even if you installed using npm install, you have to bring up the test RPC node before you can connect to that node.

Comment: i used how i can bring up the test RPC node before you can connect to that node ?

Comment: If you are using ganache, enter `ganache-cli` in another terminal and keep it running

Comment: yes thank you, i just figured it out.

Comment: Assuming you used `npm install -g ganache-cli` to install

Comment: now it giving new error `The data field must be HEX encoded data.`

Comment: It giving that error when i paste `deployedContract.deploy({
  data: bytecode,
  arguments: [listOfCandidates.map(name => web3.utils.asciiToHex(name))]
}).send({
  from: '0xDa6148749AbD18163f64Eccb467447108Ec91f3F',
  gas: 1500000,
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('0.00003', 'ether')
}).then((newContractInstance) => {
  deployedContract.options.address = newContractInstance.options.address
  console.log(newContractInstance.options.address)
});` in node

Comment: Post it as a different question

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/71637/54194 @SanjaySB

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Open a new terminal and move to the folder chapter1 (following the tutorial).
2. In the terminal run this **node_modules/.bin/ganache-cli**
3. Open a new one terminal and test node, following the 2nd section of the tutorial.
4. Don't close the terminal opened in the 1st step.

That works for me!